# C++ WH_GETMESSAGE Hook in DLL injects the DLL itself into all Processes

Tags: c++, dll, hook

i got a WH_GETMESSAGE Hook in my DLL but if i inject the DLL into a Process, it seems like the DLL gets injected into other Processes. I don't know why that should happen...

```
if(dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH )
{
    g_pGlobals->dllModule = hModule;
```

in the DllMain Function i store the Module

and then i set the hook with

```
m_hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, KeyboardHook, g_pGlobals->dllModule, 0);

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hKeyboardHook);
```

the hook it self looks like:

```
LRESULT __stdcall KeyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

 if(nCode >= 0 && nCode == HC_ACTION)
 {
     MSG* pMsg = (MSG*)lParam;

    if(pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
        g_pMenu->OnKeyPressed(pMsg->wParam);

    if (pMsg->message == WM_CHAR)
        g_pMenu->OnCharPressed(pMsg->wParam);
  }

return CallNextHookEx(g_pWindowsHooks->GetKeyboardHook(), nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and yeah g_pWindowsHooks->GetKeyboardHook() returns m_hKeyboardHook

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That is entirely normal, you passed 0 for the last argument.  MSDN says: "if this parameter is zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread.".  Use GetWindowThreadProcessId() to get the thread-id of a specific window.

Comment: Ok i will try that :)